# How can I configure the deploy Maven goal or the Maven project to be deployed with different path or name?

Tags: maven, deployment, artifactory, maven-deploy-plugin

I have the following repository available for my Maven project where I can publish snapshot artifacts:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>artifactory-releases</id>
        <url>https://artifactory.company.com/mvn-release-local</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>artifactory-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://artifactory.company.com/mvn-snapshot-local</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

How can I reconfigure my setup (`pom.xml`) or my deployment goal (`mvn deploy`) to deploy my artifacts to an alternative path in that repository or to have the files have a different name prefix in that repository.

I cannot:
* change the repository (this is the only one I have to push to)
* let my test deployments being pushed to the same location where the project is already being configured to push (based on the Maven `groupId` and `artifactId`) because I would overwrite the snapshots already being pushed there with my test

I also don't want to change my Maven `groupId` and `artifactId`. This is because it will trigger too many changes in this multi-module Maven project.

The user case: I want to make a few tests with a prototype deployment technique and I was to test it with the same repository without major refactoring. Just deploy to a slightly different/parallel path in that Maven repository.

The `deploy:deploy` goal does not seem to be [very configurable](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

The path you deploy to inside the repository is completely determined by the Maven coordinates (groupId, artifactId, version, extension, classifier) and cannot be changed.

Comment: :'( :'( :'( :'(

Comment: What about the classifier. Can I influence this? And will the artifacts still land in the `snapshotRepository` if the classifier is not `SNAPSHOT`?

Comment: 1. `SNAPSHOT` is not a classifier, but part of the version. 2. You can influence the classifier, but classifiers are for side artifacts like `javadoc` or `sources`. A side artifact cannot have its own POM. So this is probably not what you want.

Comment: :'( :'( :'( :'(

Comment: For similar cases, we used version numbers like `1.2.3-MIGRATED-SNAPSHOT` instead of `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: For now I ended up `sed`-ing the `groupId` in all `pom.xml` files replacing the artifact and dependency `groupId` elements. It is working but it is not agile enough.